# Is there such a thing as a TRULY easy to use free 3D program to create very basic and crude 3D environments with flat colours?

Tags: gratis, 3d, modeling

I've installed Blender a million times. And uninstalled it an equal number of times. When I start using it, I can place a 3D cube in the scene and that's it. I seem utterly unable to figure out how to use the thing to actually create an environment. It's hopeless.

I don't want anything made by Google or anything which runs in the browser or requires a login of any kind. It must be free, running locally as a real application.

I have indeed in the past tried "Google Sketchup", but even that I found utterly confusing.

It may very well be that my brain simply isn't capable of creating anything in 3D.

Context: I've already made a 2D (top-down) map of a landscape (mostly a mountain range), and now I'm trying to turn that into a 3D environment, for the purpose of placing the "camera" at various locations in it so that I can use these as the basis for my artistically drawn "views" of this area. I could of course go directly from my 2D map to drawing, but then it would be quite tricky in many cases to try to "see" for my inner view how the scene should be rendered.

In other words, it's not necessary for this to be super realistic. In fact, just flat-colored surfaces is what I need for this. My problem is that I've never found a 3D program which I considered to allow me to create in 3D in a sensible manner. Blender is just too confusing and complex, but I fear that there are few if any maintained/alive free 3D programs in this day and age... especially ones which are better than Blender.

Comment: There are specific landscape generator programs. But in your place I would start with a blender tutorial, then I would visit https://blender.stackexchange.com .

Comment: There HAS to exist something easier, but if you have a height map, here is a question that deals with rendering height maps in blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/133354